# Accessibility: ScrollView to auto scroll to the view which are not visible on hitting "TAB"

Tags: cocoa, accessibility, nsscrollview

Could someone let me know how can I automatically scroll the scrollView when a keyboard-only user tries to navigate between different UI Element in the ScrollView using ‘Tab’ key? When I hit "TAB" key the focus is shifted to different UI element present in the scrollView but it doesn't scroll if the UI Element is not present in the Visible Content View. How can this be achieved. Help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to scroll in code? Did you try anything?

Comment: Yeah. I want the scroll to happen automatically whenever the view getting in focus and is not in the visible area of the scrollView. I have tried `autoscroll:` with fail. I have no clue as what have I got to do. Hope you have got my requirement. Please comment.

Comment: Try `[view scrollRectToVisible:view.bounds]`.

Comment: I have tried using this. It doesn't work. I also tried `makeFirstResponder:` so that it would focus the UI element but it doesn't scroll. Could you please provide me a sample project depicting the solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solution A: Create a subclass of `NSWindow` and override `makeFirstResponder:`. `makeFirstResponder` is called when the first responder changes.

```
- (BOOL)makeFirstResponder:(NSResponder *)responder {
    BOOL madeFirstResponder = [super makeFirstResponder:responder];
    if (madeFirstResponder) {
        id view = [self firstResponder];
        // check if the new first responder is a field editor
        if (view && [view isKindOfClass:[NSTextView class]] && [view isFieldEditor])
            view = [view delegate]; // the control, usually a NSTextField
        if (view && [view isKindOfClass:[NSControl class]] && [view enclosingScrollView]) {
            NSRect rect = [view bounds];
            rect = NSInsetRect(rect, -10.0, -10.0); // add a margin
            [view scrollRectToVisible:rect];
        }
    }
    return madeFirstResponder;
}
```

Solution B: Create a subclass of `NSTextField` and other controls and override `becomeFirstResponder`.

```
- (BOOL)becomeFirstResponder {
    BOOL becameFirstResponder = [super becomeFirstResponder];
    if (becameFirstResponder) {
        if ([self enclosingScrollView]) {
            NSRect rect = [self bounds];
            rect = NSInsetRect(rect, -10.0, -10.0); // add a margin
            [self scrollRectToVisible:rect];
        }
    }
    return becameFirstResponder;
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Willek. I had tried something similar to it but it did not work, Doing it at NSWindow it works like charm.

Comment: Note that solution A has a potential bug where it will auto scroll even during mouse events that trigger setting first responder. You can prevent this by adding the following after the first line of function:
`NSEventType currentEventType = NSApp.currentEvent.type; BOOL isKeyboardEvent = currentEventType == NSEventTypeKeyUp || currentEventType == NSEventTypeKeyDown; if (!isKeyboardEvent) { return madeFirstResponder; }`

Comment: @LironYahdav Why is this a bug? How can I reproduce this bug? Does solution B also have this bug?

Comment: If you have any mouse event handler call makeFirstResponder you can reproduce the bug. I guess B would have the same bug.

Comment: I would call it a feature (autoscroll focused control into view) and not a bug.