# How to tab to a Cocoa text editing field that is scrolled out of view

Tags: cocoa, nstextfield, nsscrollview, nsresponder

I've got a window with a single text editing field next to a scrolling view.  The document view of the scrolling view contains multiple sub-views, and some of those sub-views contain text editing fields created programmatically as NSTextViews.

When the app starts the window up, the top-level text editing field is shown with focus, so it is (I think) the first responder.  The user then hits the TAB key, but the first text editing field (among many) is in a sub-view of the document view that has been scrolled out of sight of the user.

The app's default behavior is to move focus to the "next" text field.  Except the user has no idea where this is because it's out of view.

So there are two possible ways the app should behave.  Either the app should figure out that the next responder is visibly out of bounds, and prevent the TAB key from changing the current focus.  Or the app should determine which text edit field has received the new focus, and automatically scroll so that that text field is now visible to the user.  It can be argued that either scenario is logical, but I think the latter is more useful.

How does one determine that the focus has been automatically changed to a vanilla text editing control that thinks it is visible but is not, due to being clipped by a parent scroll view?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessibility: ScrollView to auto scroll to the view which are not visible on hitting "TAB"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47810930/accessibility-scrollview-to-auto-scroll-to-the-view-which-are-not-visible-on-hi)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you've got a couple of issues. They're easily solved, but none of this is automatic.

First, the order of views you cycle through when pressing the Tab key is the "key view loop". You can read up on that. It's sort of, kinda, automatic but you can express an explicit order by setting the `nextKeyView` and `previousKeyView` properties of the text fields (buttons, other controls, ...).

If you want anything in the document view of a scroll view to become visible, you need to reorient the clip view. There's a ton of ways to do that (most of them are kind of hard to understand), but what you want is so common that there's a convenience method in `NSView` that does just that: `scrollRectToVisible:`

So when your text field becomes active, all you have to do is `[textField scrollRectToVisible:textField.bounds]`.

One place to do that would be whenever the text field begins editing, which could be accomplished by attaching a delegate to the text field(s) and catching `textDidBeginEditing:` or observe the `NSControlTextDidBeginEditingNotification` notification and determine if it's one of your text fields.

Comment: The NSTextField's are sub-classed and built programmatically on the fly without knowing how many there might be before the app is launched.  The sub-class definition also declares them as : NSTextField <NSTextFieldDelegate>s.  But when I implemented textDidBeginEditing: as a method, and installed the text field object as its own delegate when it's being initialized, the method is never called.

Comment: My bad: `textDidBeginEditing:` isn't a delegate method, it's a method of `NSTextFIeld`. Just override it and see if it gets called.

Comment: Okay, I got rid of the delegate stuff and added the `textDidBeginEditing:` override method to my sub-class, as well as the related method `textShouldBeginEditing:` (which delivers YES).  Neither is called when the text field acquires focus after the user tabs to it.  Turns out that that's not an editing event.  Both are called, however, when the user types the first character into the text field.  So this strategy does not appear the correct thing to do with regards to my original question, which needs to know whether to allow tabbing to a next edit field, and if so, which one it is.

Comment: We're getting close! Then I think the solution is to override `becomeFirstResponder` and catch the moment the text field becomes the focus. If `super.becomeFirstResponder` returns `true`, then scroll the field into view.

Comment: @JamesBucanek did you see [ScrollView to auto scroll to the view which are not visible on hitting “TAB”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47810930/accessibility-scrollview-to-auto-scroll-to-the-view-which-are-not-visible-on-hi)?

Comment: @Willeke I had not seen that, but it was going to be my next suggestion. Since the original poster had already subclassed `NSTextField` it seemed easiest to start there. It’s good to know the window trick works, but it doesn’t make any sense to me that the window could change it’s first responder but somehow not inform the control.

Comment: Sorry, I meant @jsbox.

Answer (score 0):

Because I am sub-classing NSTextField, I believe the correct (or at least the working) answer is, as suggested, to override `becomeFirstResponder:` with something along the lines of the following, where `myDocView` is the scrolling content of the parent scrolling view somewhere up higher in the view hierarchy:

```
- (BOOL)becomeFirstResponder
{
    BOOL done = [super becomeFirstResponder];
    if (done) {
        // Ensure new focus ring is shown also (shouldn't be hardwired, but for now ...)
        NSSize margin = NSMakeSize(20.0, 20.0);
        // Get where text field lives in myDocView's coordinates
        NSRect r = [myDocView convertRect:[self bounds] fromView:self];
        // Try scrolling if partially visible first, and if not ...
        if (![myDocView adjustRectIntoView:r withMargin:margin]) {
            // Text edit field is not visible in parent scroll view
            // so tell document view where to scroll itself to
            margin = NSMakeSize(-30.0, -30.0);
            [myDocView specialScrollTo:self withOffset:margin];
            }
        }

    return done;
}
```

The property field `myDocView` belonging to the text edit field sub-class has to be set when the text editing object is programmatically created, so that the text editing field knows who to send the scrolling message to when it becomes first responder.  This is because in my particular case the text editing sub-classed object is actually several view levels below that of the scrolling document view.

Partly for general user-interface reasons, and partly because of the particulars of how my scrolling content view is laid out, it is necessary to do something different in three cases.  The first case is when the text editing field that is becoming the first responder is already fully visible.  That's easy, `adjustRectIntoView` does nothing but returns `YES`, because the user can see the focus ring change.

In the second case, the text editing field is partially visible.  In this case, the method `adjustRectIntoView:withMargin:` makes it fully visible (if possible, otherwise, it makes the origin area visible).  But it does so using only a minimal scrolling movement, either horizontally or vertically (and only both if necessary), leaving the field next to the nearest edge of the scrolling view's visible rect.  This "startles" the user the least.

Finally, if the field was completely invisible, then in my particular case I have to do a special analysis of other nearby views related to the text editing view so as to bring it (or them all) into view for the user to see.

Both `adjustRectIntoView:withMargin:` and `specialScrollTo:withOffset:` are methods added to the (sub-classed) `myDocView` that's being scrolled.

My latter special routine is too app-specific, but the former is pretty general and looks like this (and can be easily modified to accomplish the latter):

```
- (BOOL)adjustRectIntoView:(NSRect)r withMargin:(NSSize)margin
 {
    CGRectInset(r, -margin.width, -margin.height);
    NSRect vis = [myScroller documentVisibleRect];

    if (CGRectContainsRect(vis, r)) {
        // The enhanced rectangle `r` is already fully visible,
        // so we're done (no change)
        return(YES);
        }

    if (!CGRectIntersectsRect(vis, r)) {
        // The enhanced rectangle `r` is fully invisible, so caller
        // must apply whatever other custom strategy it needs to
        // scroll `r` into view; or don't return and fall through.
        return(NO);
        }

    // Rectangle `r` is partly visible in scroll view.  So nudge the
    // scrolling view enough to bring `r` into view near where it
    // already is, with a minimum of motion.  If `r` contains `vis`,
    // which can happen if `r` is part of a highly magnified view,
    // this gives preference to `r`'s origin becoming visible.

    NSPoint ul = r.origin;
    NSPoint ur = NSMakePoint(r.origin.x+r.size.width, r.origin.y);
    NSPoint ll = NSMakePoint(r.origin.x, r.origin.y+r.size.height);

    NSSize amt;
    if (ul.x < vis.origin.x)
        amt.width = (ul.x - vis.origin.x);
     else if (ur.x > vis.origin.x+vis.size.width)
        amt.width = (ur.x - (vis.origin.x+vis.size.width));
     else
        amt.width = 0.0;

    if (ul.y < vis.origin.y)
        amt.height = (ul.y - vis.origin.y);
     else if (ll.y > vis.origin.y+vis.size.height)
        amt.height = (ll.y - (vis.origin.y+vis.size.height));
     else
        amt.height = 0.0;

    vis.origin.x += amt.width;
    vis.origin.y += amt.height;
    [[myScroller documentView] scrollPoint:vis.origin];

    return(YES);
 }
```

Comment: Can you add `adjustRectIntoView:withMargin:` and `specialScrollTo:withOffset:`? May I ask why [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48209216/4244136) didn't work?

Comment: I didn't see it, and wasn't aware of the `enclosingScrollView` method.  Also, because my sub-class already knew what object was its scroller, no need to do a general computation up the object hierarchy, checking types, etc.  Regardless, the `scrollRectToVisible` method doesn't do the best thing in certain more complicated situations, such as needing other context to be shown alongside with the text editing field one wants to make visible.

Comment: That's why the method is `scrollRectToVisible` instead of `scrollViewToVisible`. Just add the other views to the rect.